# Cobertura creates 0% reports on multimodule app (possible config issue)

Tags: maven-3, cobertura, maven-surefire-plugin

I have problem creating reports with cobertura. Im also using **surefire plugin**, which is configured to `<skip>true</skip>` but on **integration-test phase** within execution element is set to `<skip>false</skip>`.

I configured cobertura's execution to same phase (integration-test) with `<goal>cobertura</goal>`. It worked on single module, but when i ran it on parent pom, it just creates **0%** report coverage. Also I've set `<aggregate>true</aggregate>`.

To be honest, I'm not sure how to configure cobertura with surefire properly so I'm asking for help here. I think that it might be "wrong phase" issue or the  arg set within surefire plugin or maybe something else.

I'm using cobertura maven plugin 2.5.1, maven 3.0.4, surefire 2.14 and jdk6.

Small console output (it seems like tests are running later):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BasicService 12.1.24-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ BasicService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ BasicService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\workspaces\kepler-R\trunk\commonLogic\ntas\BusinessServices\BasicService\target\BasicService-12.1.24-SNAPSHOT.j
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default) @ BasicService >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ BasicService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:instrument (default) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 9 classes.
Instrumenting 9 files to D:\workspaces\kepler-R\trunk\commonLogic\ntas\BusinessServices\BasicService\target\generated-classes\cobertura
Cobertura: Saved information on 9 classes.
Instrument time: 328ms

[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ BasicService ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default) @ BasicService <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura (default) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 9 classes.
Report time: 594ms

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 9 classes.
Report time: 813ms

[INFO] Cobertura Report generation was successful.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default) @ BasicService ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\workspaces\kepler-R\trunk\commonLogic\ntas\BusinessServices\BasicService\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.kogerusa.services.BasicServiceTest
08:48:55,371  INFO TransactionManagerFactory:148 - Standalone Bitronix transaction manager has been set
08:48:55,386  INFO TransactionManagerFactory:109 - Hibernate session factory bean has been configured for Bitronix JTA
...
```